# We are given a graph $G = (V, E)$ with maximum degree $\Delta$ and a palette of $\Delta + 1$ colors. Showing there exists a proper colouring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

We are given a graph $G = (V, E)$ with maximum degree $\Delta$ and a palette of $\Delta + 1$ colors
$\Gamma = \{c_1, \cdots , c_{\Delta+1}\}$. A coloring $\chi : V \rightarrow\Gamma$ assigns a color to every node in $V$ . We say that a coloring $\chi$ is
proper iff $\chi(u)  ≠ \chi(v)$ for all edges $(u, v) \in E$. Show that there always exists a proper coloring in $G$.

I have no idea where to start on this problem and wanted some help. I have tried using contradiction but get stuck immediately. I thought we could possibly link it to matchings but not sure.

Comment: Try induction on the number of vertices. (Also, this sounds a lot like a homework problem you should do on your own. Can you confirm that it is or is not?)

Comment: Its past exam problem. I'll try the induction, thanks!

Comment: I think you mean $\chi(u)\neq\chi(v)$

Comment: updated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an inductive  argument. We induct on $n$, the number  of vertices, that is, $n=|V|$. The base case, $n=1$, is trivial. Now, suppose, any $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|=n$ and $\max_{j\in V}{\rm deg}(j)=k$  is $(k+1)-$colorable.  Take any $G'=(V',E')$ with $|V'|=n+1$.  Select one vertex $u$, and look at the induced subgraph $G''=(V'\setminus\{u\},E'')$. This graph, by definition, has  $n$ vertices, and due to inductive hypothesis is $(k+1)-$colorable. Now, keep this coloring, and add the vertex $u$ back. Since ${\rm deg}(u)\leqslant k$, there is a  color which has not  been  used by any  of  the neighbors of $u$. Assigning this color to $u$ completes the  induction.